# How to save cache storage date with JavaScript Cache API?

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, caching, response

I'm using JavaScript's [Cache Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache) to store responses from my server to requests made by my client application. Moreover, I need a way to programmatically remove them based on when the request was originally made. Here is the code I use to store the responses:

```js
/** Searches for the corresponding cache for the given request. If found, returns
 *  the cached response. Otherwise, performs the fetch request and adds the response
 *  to cache. Returns the HTTP response.
 */
export async function fetchCachedData(request: Request) {
  const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);

  // Check if response is already cached
  const cachedResponse = await cache.match(request);
  if (cachedResponse) {
    console.debug("Using cached response for", request.url);
    return cachedResponse.clone();
  }

  // Fetch new response
  console.debug("Fetching", request.url, "...");
  const response = await fetchFromAPI(request);
  const responseDate = new Date().getTime().toString();
  response.headers.set("Date", responseDate);

  // Cache the new response
  if (
    response.ok /*&& response.clone().headers.get("Cache-Control") !== "no-store"*/
  ) {
    await cache.put(request, response.clone());
    console.info("Cached response as", response.url);
  }
  return response.clone();
}
```

This approach seems to work on browsers like Firefox, however on Chrome I get an error telling me that `headers` is read-only:
`TypeError: Failed to execute 'set' on 'Headers': Headers are immutable`

I have also tried setting the `Date` header on the server side, however it appears that not all headers set in the express-based app are honoured when cloning and retrieving them from the cache. This is why I wish to manually set the request date when the response is retrieved on the client side.

I don't necessarily need the date to be stored in the cached response's *headers*, that's just the way I have my cache filtering code set up. Ideally, the request date should be stored somewhere in the response object so that it is preserved when using `clone()` and is present in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by using the [pragma HTTP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Pragma) -- it appears to be unused as of the HTTP/1.1 spec, however when set on the server side it is preserved in the headers of the response object obtained after making a request from the `fetch()` API.

Server code (Express.js):

```js
export function headerMiddleware(
  _req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) {
  const now = new Date().getTime();
  res.setHeader("pragma", now);
  next();
}
```

This implementation is probably discouraged since `pragma` is a deprecated header and its original intention was to signal if `no-cache` is how the response is to be handled, however when I set its value to a numeric string there appear to be no errors and the solution runs smoothly. Ideally, I'd use the `Date` header, however if I set that on the server side then the header is removed upon inspection on the client.